# SSH write to a file on windows

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, phpseclib

I have a problem with the encoding of the text , I do not know what method I use for it so I can ssh using php write to file text with Czech characters as well as characters of other languages ​​.
The code currently looks like this :

```
<?php
$appname = "tést";
function prevedKodovani($string)
{
$string = iconv("utf-8", "CP852//TRANSLIT", $string);
return $string;
}
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip');

if (!$ssh->login('jmeno', 'heslo')) {

    exit('Login Failed');

}

echo $ssh->exec('cmd /c echo set jmeno='.prevedKodovani(utf8_encode($appname)).'>>C:\Users\server\Desktop\promnene.bat');
?>
```

Result in a text file :

```
set jmeno=t?(C)st
```

Comment: why do you use "CP852" ? What do you expect you will get?

Comment: Hello " CP852 " I use here because I do not know what format should I use to be able to display almost any character from any language .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of factors to consider. What is the character encoding of the *.php file? If it's UTF8 then `tést` will already be UTF8 encoded and your `utf8_encode` call will double UTF8 encode `tést`.

You also gotta consider the character encoding that `C:\Users\server\Desktop\promnene.bat` is being loaded with. Are you loading it with Notepad (which supports ANSI, Unicode and UTF-8) or Notepad++ (which supports a whole lot more character encodings) or something else? If you take a CP852 file and load it as a UTF-8 file you won't get the characters you might be expecting.

Personally, when I work with batch files, I usually just do everything in ANSI / ISO-8859-1. This means no `utf8_encode` call and no `iconv` call.